# File permissions log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I using `log4j2`. My config look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">{%X{taskId}} %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level %M(%F:%L) - %msg%n</Property>
        <Property name="folder">logs</Property>
        <Property name="info-filename">test</Property>
        <Property name="error-filename">test-error</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file" fileName="${folder}/${info-filename}.log" filePattern="${folder}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/${info-filename}-%d{yyyy-dd-MM}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4 GB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="999999"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="file-error" fileName="${folder}/${error-filename}.log" filePattern="${folder}/$${date:yyyy-MM-dd}/${error-filename}-%d{yyyy-dd-MM}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4 GB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="999999"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file-error" level="error" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="file-error" level="error" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.springframework.ws.client" level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="file-error" level="error" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I want the folder `logs` and all the files attached to it to be created with  rights `rw-rw-r--`. Also, for the group and the owner to have the same as the user who launched the program. How can I configure my `log4j2` to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Log4j2 since 2.9.0 supports such feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1699

You can use additional attributes for element `RollingFile` like

```
<RollingFile ... filePermissions="rw-rw-r--">
```

Comment: with what permissions will the parent folder `logs` be created?

Comment: I'm not sure but I would expect that each file/folder created by `RollingFile` policy should have same permissions as defined. Could you check it?

Comment: Folder has attributes `drwxrwxr-x`, And the files, such as I specified in the config