# Log4j2, how to deal with acces denied exception

Tags: log4j2

I'm using RollingFile appender to store logs in file.
Unfortunately, sometimes logs file is created from root account,
as a result of which no logs are saved into file.

An exception occurs during:
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.RollingFileManagerFactory#createManager
triggered

"ERROR RollingFileManager (target/logs/file.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\logs\file.log (Access is denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: target\logs\file.log (Access is denied)"

I would like to prevent application run in this situation.
I've tried to use FailoverAppender connected to RollingFileAppender, but it's not triggered at all.

Any ideas how to deal with it ?

Comment: You can set default file permission to get around with this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810431/file-permissions-log4j2

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same problem and it was because of a mistake in my `log4j2.properies`.

I set `appender.rolling.fileName` to an alreay existed directory/file

I recommend u to double check ur configuration and search for the same mistake maybe.

hope it is helpful for the others who have same issue